Problem with syntactic difference in C++ and Fortran languages
There is code in Fortran that I am trying to translate into C++. Apparently, I misunderstood the Fortran syntax somewhere and that's why I'm getting a problem on line 94. I looked at the values of the components on line 94 and realized that, with a high probability, I incorrectly calculated the two-dimensional array A. But I double-checked its calculations many times and cannot find any errors. Please tell me what needs to be done for the code to work correctly? (I used debuger, I’m inclined to believe that I messed something up with the difference in syntax in the languages)
С++:
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

void initl(double& sxxs, double& sxxn, double& syys, double& syyn, double& sxys, double& sxyn, double& uxs, double& uxn, double& uys, double& uyn)
{
    sxxs = 0.0;
    sxxn = 0.0;
    syys = 0.0;
    syyn = 0.0;
    sxys = 0.0;
    sxyn = 0.0;

    uxs = 0.0;
    uxn = 0.0;
    uys = 0.0;
    uyn = 0.0;
}
void coeff(double x, double y, double cx, double cy, double a, double cosb, double sinb, int msym, double pi, double con, double cond, double pr1, double pr2, double pr3, double& uxs, double& uxn, double& uys, double& uyn, double& sxxs, double& sxxn, double& syys, double& syyn, double& sxys, double& sxyn) {

    double cos2b, sin2b, xb, yb, r1s, r2s, fl1, fl2, fb1, fb2, fb3, fb4, fb5, uxps, uxpn, uyps, uypn;
    double sxxps, sxxpn, syyps, syypn, sxyps, sxypn;

    cos2b = cosb * cosb - sinb * sinb;
    sin2b = 2.0 * sinb * cosb;

    xb = (x - cx) * cosb + (y - cy) * sinb;
    yb = -(x - cx) * sinb + (y - cy) * cosb;

    r1s = (xb - a) * (xb - a) + yb * yb;
    r2s = (xb + a) * (xb + a) + yb * yb;
    fl1 = 0.5 * log(r1s);//log - натуральный логарифм
    fl2 = 0.5 * log(r2s);
    fb2 = con * (fl1 - fl2);
    if (yb != 0.0) {
        fb3 = -con * (atan((xb + a) / yb) - atan((xb - a) / yb));
    }
    else
    {
        fb3 = 0.0;
        if (abs(xb) < a) {
            fb3 = con * pi;
        }
    }
    fb1 = yb * fb3 + con * ((xb - a) * fl1 - (xb + a) * fl2);
    fb4 = con * (yb / r1s - yb / r2s);
    fb5 = con * ((xb - a) / r1s - (xb + a) / r2s);

    uxps = cond * (pr3 * cosb * fb1 + yb * (sinb * fb2 + cosb * fb3));
    uxpn = cond * (-pr3 * sinb * fb1 - yb * (cosb * fb2 - sinb * fb3));
    uyps = cond * (pr3 * sinb * fb1 - yb * (cosb * fb2 - sinb * fb3));
    uypn = cond * (pr3 * cosb * fb1 - yb * (sinb * fb2 + cosb * fb3));

    sxxps = fb2 + pr2 * (cos2b * fb2 - sin2b * fb3) + yb * (cos2b * fb4 + sin2b * fb5);
    sxxpn = fb3 - pr1 * (sin2b * fb2 + cos2b * fb3) + yb * (sin2b * fb4 - cos2b * fb5);
    syyps = fb2 - pr2 * (cos2b * fb2 - sin2b * fb3) - yb * (cos2b * fb4 + sin2b * fb5);
    syypn = fb3 + pr1 * (sin2b * fb2 + cos2b * fb3) - yb * (sin2b * fb4 - cos2b * fb5);
    sxyps = pr2 * (sin2b * fb2 + cos2b * fb3) + yb * (sin2b * fb4 - cos2b * fb5);
    sxypn = pr1 * (cos2b * fb2 - sin2b * fb3) - yb * (cos2b * fb4 + sin2b * fb5);

    uxs = uxs + msym * uxps;
    uxn = uxn + uxpn;
    uys = uys + msym * uyps;
    uyn = uyn + uypn;

    sxxs = sxxs + msym * sxxps;
    sxxn = sxxn + sxxpn;
    syys = syys + msym * syyps;
    syyn = syyn + syypn;
    sxys = sxys + msym * sxyps;
    sxyn = sxyn + sxypn;
}

void solve(int n, vector<vector<double>>& a, vector<double>& b, vector<double>& x) {
    int nb, l;
    double xm;
    nb = n - 1;
    for (int j = 0; j < nb; ++j) {// 1 -> 0; "<=" -> "<"
        l = j + 1;
        for (int jj = l; jj < n; ++jj) {// "<=" -> "<"
            xm = a[jj][j] / a[j][j];
            for (int i = j; i < n; ++i) {// "<=" -> "<"
                a[jj][i] = a[jj][i] - a[j][i] * xm;
            }
            b[jj] = b[jj] - b[j] * xm;
        }
    }

    int jj;
    double summ;
    summ = 0.0;
    x[n-1] = b[n-1] / a[n-1][n-1];
    for (int j = 0; j < nb; ++j) {// 1 -> 0; "<=" -> "<"
        jj = n - j;
        l = jj + 1;
        summ = 0.0;
        for (int i = l; i < n; ++i) {// "<=" -> "<"
            summ = summ + a[jj][i] * x[i];
        }
        x[jj] = (b[jj] - summ) / a[jj][jj];
    }
}

int main()
{
    int numbs, numos, ksym;
    cin >> numbs >> numos >> ksym;
    double pr, e, xsym, ysym;
    cin >> pr >> e >> xsym >> ysym;
    double pxx, pyy, pxy;
    cin >> pxx >> pyy >> pxy;
    cout << " number of straight-line segments (each counting at least one boundary element) used to define boundaries = " << numbs << endl;
    cout << " number of straight-line segments used to specify other locations (i.e., not on a boundary) where results are to be found = " << numos << endl;
    cout << " the lines x = xs = " << xsym << " and y = ys = " << ysym << " are lines of symmetry." << endl;
    cout << " poissons ratio = " << pr << endl;
    cout << " youngs modulus = " << e << endl;
    cout << " xx-component of field stress = " << pxx << endl;
    cout << " yy-component of field stress = " << pyy << endl;
    cout << " xy-component of field stress = " << pxy << endl;
    /*cout << "" <<  << endl;*/
    double pi, con, cond, pr1, pr2, pr3;

    pi = 4.0 * atan(1.0);
    con = 1.0 / (4.0 * pi * (1.0 - pr));
    cond = (1.0 + pr) / e;
    pr1 = 1.0 - 2.0 * pr;
    pr2 = 2.0 * (1.0 - pr);
    pr3 = 3.0 - 4.0 * pr;

    //define locations, sizes, orientations and boundary conditions of boundary elements.

    int numbe, num, kode, m, mn, ms;
    vector<int> kod;
    double xbeg, ybeg, xend, yend, bvs, bvn, xd, yd, sw;
    vector<double> xm, ym, a, sinbet, cosbet, b;

    numbe = 0;
    for (int n = 1; n <= numbs; ++n) {
        cin >> num >> xbeg >> ybeg >> xend >> yend >> kode >> bvs >> bvn;
        xd = (xend - xbeg) / num;
        yd = (yend - ybeg) / num;
        sw = sqrt(xd * xd + yd * yd);
        for (int ne = 1; ne <= num; ++ne) {
            numbe = numbe + 1;
            xm.push_back(xbeg + 0.5 * (2.0 * ne - 1.0) * xd);
            ym.push_back(ybeg + 0.5 * (2.0 * ne - 1.0) * yd);
            a.push_back(0.5 * sw);
            sinbet.push_back(yd / sw);
            cosbet.push_back(xd / sw);
            kod.push_back(kode);
            b.push_back(bvs);
            b.push_back(bvn);
        }
    }
    cout << "boundary element data." << endl;
    cout << "element kode x (center) y (center) length   angle us or sigma-sun or sigma-n" << endl;
    double size, angle;
    for (int m = 0; m < numbe; ++m) {
        size = 2.0 * a[m];
        angle = 180.0 * atan2(sinbet[m], cosbet[m]) / pi;
        cout << m + 1 << "       " << kod[m] << "    " << xm[m] << "     " << ym[m] << "    " << size << "   " << angle << " " << b[2 * m] << " " << b[2 * m + 1] << endl;
    }

    //adjust stress boundary values to account for initial stresses.

    int nn, ns;
    double cosb, sinb, sigs, sign;
    for (int n = 0; n < numbe; ++n) {// 1 -> 0; "<=" -> "<"
        nn = 2 * n + 1;// 2 * i
        ns = nn - 1;
        cosb = cosbet[n];
        sinb = sinbet[n];
        sigs = (pyy - pxx) * sinb * cosb + pxy * (cosb * cosb - sinb * sinb);
        sign = pxx * sinb * sinb - 2. * pxy * sinb * cosb + pyy * cosb * cosb;
        b[ns] = b[ns] - sigs;
        b[nn] = b[nn] - sign;
        b[nn] = b[nn] - sign;
        b[ns] = b[ns] - sigs;
    }

    //compute influence coefficients and set up system of algebraic equations.

    int in, is, jn, js;
    double xi, yi, cosbi, sinbi, xj, yj, cosbj, sinbj, aj;
    double sxxs, sxxn, syys, syyn, sxys, sxyn, uxs, uxn, uys, uyn;
    vector<vector<double>> c(12, vector<double>(12, 0));
    for (int i = 0; i < numbe; ++i) {// 1 -> 0; "<=" -> "<"
        in = 2 * i + 1;// 2 * i
        is = in - 1;
        xi = xm[i];
        yi = ym[i];
        cosbi = cosbet[i];
        sinbi = sinbet[i];
        kode = kod[i];
        for (int j = 0; j < numbe; ++j) {// 1 -> 0; "<=" -> "<"
            jn = 2 * j + 1;// 2 * j
            js = jn - 1;
            initl(sxxs, sxxn, syys, syyn, sxys, sxyn, uxs, uxn, uys, uyn);
            xj = xm[j];
            yj = ym[j];
            cosbj = cosbet[j];
            sinbj = sinbet[j];
            aj = a[j];
            coeff(xi, yi, xj, yj, aj, cosbj, sinbj, +1, pi, con, cond, pr1, pr2, pr3, uxs, uxn, uys, uyn, sxxs, sxxn, syys, syyn, sxys, sxyn);
            if (ksym == 1) {
                continue;
            }
            else if (ksym == 2) {
                xj = 2. * xsym - xm[j];
                coeff(xi, yi, xj, yj, aj, cosbj, -sinbj, -1, pi, con, cond, pr1, pr2, pr3, uxs, uxn, uys, uyn, sxxs, sxxn, syys, syyn, sxys, sxyn);
                continue;
            }
            else if (ksym == 3) {
                yj = 2. * ysym - ym[j];
                coeff(xi, yi, xj, yj, aj, -cosbj, sinbj, -1, pi, con, cond, pr1, pr2, pr3, uxs, uxn, uys, uyn, sxxs, sxxn, syys, syyn, sxys, sxyn);
                continue;
            }
            else if (ksym == 4) {
                xj = 2. * xsym - xm[j];
                coeff(xi, yi, xj, yj, aj, cosbj, -sinbj, -1, pi, con, cond, pr1, pr2, pr3, uxs, uxn, uys, uyn, sxxs, sxxn, syys, syyn, sxys, sxyn);
                xj = xm[j];
                yj = 2. * ysym - ym[j];
                coeff(xi, yi, xj, yj, aj, -cosbj, sinbj, -1, pi, con, cond, pr1, pr2, pr3, uxs, uxn, uys, uyn, sxxs, sxxn, syys, syyn, sxys, sxyn);
                xj = 2. * xsym - xm[j];
                coeff(xi, yi, xj, yj, aj, -cosbj, -sinbj, +1, pi, con, cond, pr1, pr2, pr3, uxs, uxn, uys, uyn, sxxs, sxxn, syys, syyn, sxys, sxyn);
            }

            if (ksym == 1) {
                c[is][js] = (syys - sxxs) * sinbi * cosbi + sxys * (cosbi * cosbi - sinbi * sinbi);
                c[is][jn] = (syyn - sxxn) * sinbi * cosbi + sxyn * (cosbi * cosbi - sinbi * sinbi);
                c[in][js] = sxxs * sinbi * sinbi - 2. * sxys * sinbi * cosbi + syys * cosbi * cosbi;
                c[in][jn] = sxxn * sinbi * sinbi - 2. * sxyn * sinbi * cosbi + syyn * cosbi * cosbi;
                continue;
            }
            else if (ksym == 2) {
                c[is][js] = uxs * cosbi + uys * sinbi;
                c[is][jn] = uxn * cosbi + uyn * sinbi;
                c[in][js] = -uxs * sinbi + uys * cosbi;
                c[in][jn] = -uxn * sinbi + uyn * cosbi;
                continue;
            }
            else if (ksym == 3) {
                c[is][js] = uxs * cosbi + uys * sinbi;
                c[is][jn] = uxn * cosbi + uyn * sinbi;
                c[in][js] = sxxs * sinbi * sinbi - 2. * sxys * sinbi * cosbi + syys * cosbi * cosbi;
                c[in][jn] = sxxn * sinbi * sinbi - 2. * sxyn * sinbi * cosbi + syyn * cosbi * cosbi;
                continue;
            }
            else if (ksym == 4) {
                c[is][js] = (syys - sxxs) * sinbi * cosbi + sxys * (cosbi * cosbi - sinbi * sinbi);
                c[is][jn] = (syyn - sxxn) * sinbi * cosbi + sxyn * (cosbi * cosbi - sinbi * sinbi);
                c[in][js] = -uxs * sinbi + uys * cosbi;
                c[in][jn] = -uxn * sinbi + uyn * cosbi;
            }
        }
    }

    //solve system of algebraic equations.

    int n;
    vector<double> p;
    n = 2 * numbe;
    solve(n, c, b, a);

    // compute boundary displacements and stresses.
    
    cout << endl << "displacements and stresses at midpoints of boundary elements." << endl << endl << "element ux uy us un sigxx sigyy sigxy sigma-s sigma-n sigma-t" << endl;
    
    double ux, uy, sigxx, sigyy, sigxy, us, un, sigt;

    for (int i = 0; i < numbe; ++i) {// 1 -> 0; "<=" -> "<"
        xi = xm[i];
        yi = ym[i];
        cosbi = cosbet[i];
        sinbi = sinbet[i];

        ux = 0.0;
        uy = 0.0;
        sigxx = pxx;
        sigyy = pyy;
        sigxy = pxy;

        for (int j = 0; j < numbe; ++j) {// 1 -> 0; "<=" -> "<"
            jn = 2 * j;
            js = jn - 1;
            initl(sxxs, sxxn, syys, syyn, sxys, sxyn, uxs, uxn, uys, uyn);
            xj = xm[j];
            yj = ym[j];
            aj = a[j];
            cosbj = cosbet[j];
            sinbj = sinbet[j];
            coeff(xi, yi, xj, yj, aj, cosbj, sinbj, +1, pi, con, cond, pr1, pr2, pr3, uxs, uxn, uys, uyn, sxxs, sxxn, syys, syyn, sxys, sxyn);
            if (ksym == 1) {
                continue;
            }
            if (ksym == 2) {
                xj = 2.0 * xsym - xm[j];
                coeff(xi, yi, xj, yj, aj, cosbj, -sinbj, -1, pi, con, cond, pr1, pr2, pr3, uxs, uxn, uys, uyn, sxxs, sxxn, syys, syyn, sxys, sxyn);
                continue;
            }
            if (ksym == 3) {
                yj = 2.0 * ysym - ym[j];
                coeff(xi, yi, xj, yj, aj, -cosbj, sinbj, -1, pi, con, cond, pr1, pr2, pr3, uxs, uxn, uys, uyn, sxxs, sxxn, syys, syyn, sxys, sxyn);
                continue;
            }
            if (ksym == 4) {
                xj = 2.0 * xsym - xm[j];
                coeff(xi, yi, xj, yj, aj, cosbj, -sinbj, -1, pi, con, cond, pr1, pr2, pr3, uxs, uxn, uys, uyn, sxxs, sxxn, syys, syyn, sxys, sxyn);
                xj = xm[j];
                yj = 2.0 * ysym - ym[j];
                coeff(xi, yi, xj, yj, aj, -cosbj, sinbj, -1, pi, con, cond, pr1, pr2, pr3, uxs, uxn, uys, uyn, sxxs, sxxn, syys, syyn, sxys, sxyn);
                xj = 2.0 * xsym - xm[j];
                coeff(xi, yi, xj, yj, aj, -cosbj, -sinbj, +1, pi, con, cond, pr1, pr2, pr3, uxs, uxn, uys, uyn, sxxs, sxxn, syys, syyn, sxys, sxyn);
            }

            ux = ux + uxs * p[js] + uxn * p[jn];
            uy = uy + uys * p[js] + uyn * p[jn];
            sigxx = sigxx + sxxs * p[js] + sxxn * p[jn];
            sigyy = sigyy + syys * p[js] + syyn * p[jn];
            sigxy = sigxy + sxys * p[js] + sxyn * p[jn];
        }

        us = ux * cosbi + uy * sinbi;
        un = -ux * sinbi + uy * cosbi;
        sigs = (sigyy - sigxx) * sinbi * cosbi + sigxy * (cosbi * cosbi - sinbi * sinbi);
        sign = sigxx * sinbi * sinbi - 2.0 * sigxy * sinbi * cosbi + sigyy * cosbi * cosbi;
        sigt = sigxx * cosbi * cosbi + 2.0 * sigxy * cosbi * sinbi + sigyy * sinbi * sinbi;

        cout << i << " " << ux << " " << uy << " " << us << " " << un << " " << sigxx << " " << sigyy << " " << sigxy << " " << sigs << " " << sign << " " << sigt << endl;
    }
}

Fortran:
!
      COMMON/S1/PI,PR,PR1,PR2,PR3,CON,COND
      COMMON/S2/SXXS,SXXN,SYYS,SYYN,SXYS,SXYN,UXS,UXN,UYS,UYN
      COMMON/S3/C(100,100),B(100),P(100)
!
      DIMENSION XM(50),YM(50),A(50),COSBET(50),SINBET(50),KOD(50)
      DIMENSION TITLE(20)
!
      READ (5,1) (TITLE(I),I=1,20)
      WRITE (6,2) (TITLE(I),I=1,20)
      READ (5,3) NUMBS,NUMOS,KSYM
      READ (5,4) PR,E,XSYM,YSYM
      READ (5,5) PXX,PYY,PXY
      WRITE (6,6) NUMBS,NUMOS
      GO TO (80,85,90,95), KSYM
80    WRITE (6,7)
      GO TO 100
85    WRITE (6,8) XSYM
      GO TO 100
90    WRITE (6,9) YSYM
      GO TO 100
95    WRITE (6,10) XSYM,YSYM
!
100   CONTINUE
      WRITE (6,11) PR,E
      WRITE (6,12) PXX,PYY,PXY
!
      PI=4.*ATAN(1.)
      CON=1./(4.*PI*(1.-PR))
      COND=(1.+PR)/E
      PR1=1.-2.*PR
      PR2=2.*(1.-PR)
      PR3=3.-4.*PR
!
!   DEFINE LOCATIONS,SIZES,ORIENTATIONS AND BOUNDARY CONDITIONS OF BOUNDARY ELEMENTS
!
      NUMBE=0
      DO 110 N=1,NUMBS
      READ (5,14) NUM,XBEG,YBEG,XEND,YEND,KODE,BVS,BVN
      XD=(XEND-XBEG)/NUM
      YD=(YEND-YBEG)/NUM
      SW=SQRT(XD*XD+YD*YD)
!
      DO 110 NE=1,NUM
      NUMBE=NUMBE+1
      M=NUMBE
      XM(M)=XBEG+0.5*(2.*NE-1.)*XD
      YM(M)=YBEG+0.5*(2.*NE-1.)*YD
      A(M)=0.5*SW
      SINBET(M)=YD/SW
      COSBET(M)=XD/SW
      KOD(M)=KODE
      MN=2*M
      MS=MN-1
      B(MS)=BVS
110   B(MN)=BVN
      WRITE (6,13)
      DO 115 M=1,NUMBE
      SIZE=2.*A(M)
      ANGLE=180.*ATAN2(SINBET(M),COSBET(M))/PI
      WRITE (6,15) M,KOD(M),XM(M),YM(M),SIZE,ANGLE,B(2*M-1),B(2*M)
115   CONTINUE
!
!   ADJUST STRESS BOUNDARY VALUES TO ACCOUNT FOR INITIAL STRESSES.
!
      DO 150 N=1,NUMBE
      NN=2*N
      NS=NN-1
      COSB=COSBET(N)
      SINB=SINBET(N)
      SIGS=(PYY-PXX)*SINB*COSB+PXY*(COSB*COSB-SINB*SINB)
      SIG_N=PXX*SINB*SINB-2.*PXY*SINB*COSB+PYY*COSB*COSB
      GO TO (120,150,130,140),KOD(N)
120   B(NS)=B(NS)-SIGS
      B(NN)=B(NN)-SIG_N
      GO TO 150
130   B(NN)=B(NN)-SIG_N
      GO TO 150
140   B(NS)=B(NS)-SIGS
150   CONTINUE
!
!   COMPUTE INFLUENCE COEFFICIENTS AND SET UP SYSTEM OF ALGEBRAIC EQUATIONS.
!
      DO 300 I=1,NUMBE
      IN=2*I
      IS=IN-1
      XI=XM(I)
      YI=YM(I)
      COSBI=COSBET(I)
      SINBI=SINBET(I)
      KODE=KOD(I)
!
      DO 300 J=1,NUMBE
      JN=2*J
      JS=JN-1
      CALL INITL
      XJ=XM(J)
      YJ=YM(J)
      COSBJ=COSBET(J)
      SINBJ=SINBET(J)
      AJ=A(J)
      CALL COEFF(XI,YI,XJ,YJ,AJ,COSBJ,SINBJ,+1)
      GO TO (240,210,220,230),KSYM
!
210   XJ=2.*XSYM-XM(J)
      CALL COEFF(XI,YI,XJ,YJ,AJ,COSBJ,-SINBJ,-1)
      GO TO 240
!
220   YJ=2.*YSYM-YM(J)
      CALL COEFF(XI,YI,XJ,YJ,AJ,-COSBJ,SINBJ,-1)
      GO TO 240
!
230   XJ=2.*XSYM-XM(J)
      CALL COEFF(XI,YI,XJ,YJ,AJ,COSBJ,-SINBJ,-1)
      XJ=XM(J)
      YJ=2.*YSYM-YM(J)
      CALL COEFF(XI,YI,XJ,YJ,AJ,-COSBJ,SINBJ,-1)
      XJ=2.*XSYM-XM(J)
      CALL COEFF(XI,YI,XJ,YJ,AJ,-COSBJ,-SINBJ,+1)
!
240   CONTINUE
      GO TO (250,260,270,280),KODE
!
250   C(IS,JS)=(SYYS-SXXS)*SINBI*COSBI+SXYS*(COSBI*COSBI-SINBI*SINBI)
      C(IS,JN)=(SYYN-SXXN)*SINBI*COSBI+SXYN*(COSBI*COSBI-SINBI*SINBI)
      C(IN,JS)=SXXS*SINBI*SINBI-2.*SXYS*SINBI*COSBI+SYYS*COSBI*COSBI
      C(IN,JN)=SXXN*SINBI*SINBI-2.*SXYN*SINBI*COSBI+SYYN*COSBI*COSBI
      GO TO 300
!
260   C(IS,JS)=UXS*COSBI+UYS*SINBI
      C(IS,JN)=UXN*COSBI+UYN*SINBI
      C(IN,JS)=-UXS*SINBI+UYS*COSBI
      C(IN,JN)=-UXN*SINBI+UYN*COSBI
      GO TO 300
!
270   C(IS,JS)=UXS*COSBI+UYS*SINBI
      C(IS,JN)=UXN*COSBI+UYN*SINBI
      C(IN,JS)=SXXS*SINBI*SINBI-2.*SXYS*SINBI*COSBI+SYYS*COSBI*COSBI
      C(IN,JN)=SXXN*SINBI*SINBI-2.*SXYN*SINBI*COSBI+SYYN*COSBI*COSBI
      GO TO 300
!
280   C(IS,JS)=(SYYS-SXXS)*SINBI*COSBI+SXYS*(COSBI*COSBI-SINBI*SINBI)
      C(IS,JN)=(SYYN-SXXN)*SINBI*COSBI+SXYN*(COSBI*COSBI-SINBI*SINBI)
      C(IN,JS)=-UXS*SINBI+UYS*COSBI
      C(IN,JN)=-UXN*SINBI+UYN*COSBI
!
300   CONTINUE
!
!   SOLVE SYSTEM OF ALGEBRAIC EQUATIONS.
!
      N=2*NUMBE
      CALL SOLVE(N)
!
!   COMPUTE BOUNDARY DISPLACEMENTS AND STRESSES.
!
      WRITE (6,16)
      DO 600 I=1,NUMBE
      XI=XM(I)
      YI=YM(I)
      COSBI=COSBET(I)
      SINBI=SINBET(I)
!
      UX=0.
      UY=0.
      SIGXX=PXX
      SIGYY=PYY
      SIGXY=PXY
!
      DO 570 J=1,NUMBE
      JN=2*J
      JS=JN-1
      CALL INITL
      XJ=XM(J)
      YJ=YM(J)
      AJ=A(J)
      COSBJ=COSBET(J)
      SINBJ=SINBET(J)
      CALL COEFF(XI,YI,XJ,YJ,AJ,COSBJ,SINBJ,+1)
      GO TO (540,510,520,530),KSYM
!
510   XJ=2.*XSYM-XM(J)
      CALL COEFF(XI,YI,XJ,YJ,AJ,COSBJ,-SINBJ,-1)
      GO TO 540
!
520   YJ=2.*YSYM-YM(J)
      CALL COEFF(XI,YI,XJ,YJ,AJ,-COSBJ,SINBJ,-1)
      GO TO 540
!
530   XJ=2.*XSYM-XM(J)
      CALL COEFF(XI,YI,XJ,YJ,AJ,COSBJ,-SINBJ,-1)
      XJ=XM(J)
      YJ=2.*YSYM-YM(J)
      CALL COEFF(XI,YI,XJ,YJ,AJ,-COSBJ,SINBJ,-1)
      XJ=2.*XSYM-XM(J)
      CALL COEFF(XI,YI,XJ,YJ,AJ,-COSBJ,-SINBJ,+1)
!
540   CONTINUE
!
      UX=UX+UXS*P(JS)+UXN*P(JN)
      UY=UY+UYS*P(JS)+UYN*P(JN)
      SIGXX=SIGXX+SXXS*P(JS)+SXXN*P(JN)
      SIGYY=SIGYY+SYYS*P(JS)+SYYN*P(JN)
      SIGXY=SIGXY+SXYS*P(JS)+SXYN*P(JN)
!
570   CONTINUE
!
      US=UX*COSBI+UY*SINBI
      UN=-UX*SINBI+UY*COSBI
      SIGS=(SIGYY-SIGXX)*SINBI*COSBI+SIGXY*(COSBI*COSBI-SINBI*SINBI)
      SIG_N=SIGXX*SINBI*SINBI-2.*SIGXY*SINBI*COSBI+SIGYY*COSBI*COSBI
      SIGT=SIGXX*COSBI*COSBI+2.*SIGXY*COSBI*SINBI+SIGYY*SINBI*SINBI
!
      WRITE (6,17) I,UX,UY,US,UN,SIGXX,SIGYY,SIGXY,SIGS,SIG_N,SIGT
!
600   CONTINUE
!
!   COMPUTE DISPLACEMENTS AND STRESSES AT SPECIFIED POINTS IN BOD
!
      IF (NUMOS.LE.0) GO TO 900
      WRITE (6,18)
      NPOINT=0
      DO 890 N=1,NUMOS
      READ (5,19) XBEG,YBEG,XEND,YEND,NUMPB
      NUMP=NUMPB+1
      DELX=(XEND-XBEG)/NUMP
      DELY=(YEND-YBEG)/NUMP
      IF (NUMPB.GT.0) NUMP=NUMP+1
      IF (DELX**2+DELY**2.EQ.0.) NUMP=1
!
      DO 890 NI=1,NUMP
      XP=XBEG+(NI-1)*DELX
      YP=YBEG+(NI-1)*DELY
!
      UX=0.
      UY=0.
      SIGXX=PXX
      SIGYY=PYY
      SIGXY=PXY
!
      DO 880 J=1,NUMBE
      JN=2*J
      JS=JN-1
      CALL INITL
      XJ=XM(J)
      YJ=YM(J)
      AJ=A(J)
!
      IF (SQRT((XP-XJ)**2+(YP-YJ)**2).LT.2.*AJ) GO TO 890
!
      COSBJ=COSBET(J)
      SINBJ=SINBET(J)
      CALL COEFF(XP,YP,XJ,YJ,AJ,COSBJ,SINBJ,+1)
      GO TO (840,810,820,830),KSYM
!
810   XJ=2.*XSYM-XM(J)
      CALL COEFF(XP,YP,XJ,YJ,AJ,COSBJ,-SINBJ,-1)
      GO TO 840
!
820   YJ=2.*YSYM-YM(J)
      CALL COEFF(XP,YP,XJ,YJ,AJ,-COSBJ,SINBJ,-1)
      GO TO 840
!
830   XJ=2.*XSYM-XM(J)
      CALL COEFF(XP,YP,XJ,YJ,AJ,COSBJ,-SINBJ,-1)
      XJ=XM(J)
      YJ=2.*YSYM-YM(J)
      CALL COEFF(XP,YP,XJ,YJ,AJ,-COSBJ,SINBJ,-1)
      XJ=2.*XSYM-XM(J)
      CALL COEFF(XP,YP,XJ,YJ,AJ,-COSBJ,-SINBJ,+1)
!
840   CONTINUE
!
      UX=UX+UXS*P(JS)+UXN*P(JN)
      UY=UY+UYS*P(JS)+UYN*P(JN)
      SIGXX=SIGXX+SXXS*P(JS)+SXXN*P(JN)
      SIGYY=SIGYY+SYYS*P(JS)+SYYN*P(JN)
      SIGXY=SIGXY+SXYS*P(JS)+SXYN*P(JN)
!
880   CONTINUE
!
      NPOINT=NPOINT+1
      WRITE (6,20) NPOINT,XP,YP,UX,UY,SIGXX,SIGYY,SIGXY
!
890   CONTINUE
!
900   CONTINUE
!
!   FORMAT STATEMENTS.
!
1     FORMAT (20A4)
2     FORMAT (1H1,/,25X,20A4,/)
3     FORMAT (3I4)
4     FORMAT (F6.2,E11.4,2F12.4)
5     FORMAT (3E11.4)
6     FORMAT (/,109H NUMBE_R OF STRAIGHT-LINE SEGMENTS (EACH COUNTING A&
     T LEAST ONE BOUNDARY ELEMENT) USED T_O DEFINE BOUNDARIES =,I3,//,12&
     6H NUMBE_R OF STRAIGHT-LINE SEGMENTS USED T_O SPECIFY OTHER LOCATION&
     S (IE, NO_T ON A BOUNDARY) WHER_E RESULTS ARE T_O BE FOUND =,I3)
7     FORMAT (/,31H NO SYMMETRY CONDITIONS IMPOSED)
8     FORMAT (/,18H THE LINE X = XS =, F12.4,23H I_S A LINE OF SYMMETRY)
9     FORMAT (/,18H THE LINE Y = YS =, F12.4,23H I_S A LINE OF SYMMETRY)
10    FORMAT (/,19H THE LINES X = XS =,F12.4,13H AND Y = YS =, F12.4,&
     22H ARE LINES OF SYMMETRY)
11    FORMAT (/,17H POISSONS RATIO =,F6.2,//,17H YOUNGS MODULUS =,E11.&
     4)
12    FORMAT (/,31H XX-COMPONENT OF FIELD STRESS =,E11.4,//,31H YY-COMPO&
     NENT OF FIELD STRESS =,E11.4,//,31H XY-COMPONENT OF FIELD STRESS =&
     ,E11.4)
13    FORMAT (1H1,/,27H     BOUNDARY ELEMENT DAT_A,//,96H  ELEMENT     K&
     ODE  X (CENTER)  Y (CENTER)      LENGTH       ANGLE  US OR SIGMA-S&
       UN OR SIGMA-N,/)
14    FORMAT (I4,4F12.4,I4,2E11.4)
15    FORMAT (2I9,3F12.4,F12.2,2E15.4)
16    FORMAT (1H1,/,65H     DISPLACEMENTS AND STRESSES AT MIDPOINTS OF B&
     OUNDARY ELEMENTS,//,40H   ELEMENT        UX        UY        US,&
      60H UN        SIGXX     SIGYY     SIGXY     SIGMA-S     SIGMA-N,&
      10H   SIGMA-T,/)
17    FORMAT (I10,4F10.6,6F10.1)
18    FORMAT (1H1,/,64H     DISPLACEMENTS AND STRESSES AT SPECIFIED POIN&
     TS I_N THE BODY,//,93H    POINT    X CO-ORD    Y CO-ORD          U&
     X          UY       SIGXX       SIGYY       SIGXY,/)
19    FORMAT (4F12.4,I4)
20    FORMAT (I9,2F12.4,2F12.6,3F12.1)
!
      END
!
      SUBROUTINE INITL
!
      COMMON/S2/SXXS,SXXN,SYYS,SYYN,SXYS,SXYN,UXS,UXN,UYS,UYN
!
      SXXS=0.
      SXXN=0.
      SYYS=0.
      SYYN=0.
      SXYS=0.
      SXYN=0.
!
      UXS=0.
      UXN=0.
      UYS=0.
      UYN=0.
!
      RETURN
      END
!
      SUBROUTINE COEFF(X,Y,CX,CY,A,COSB,SINB,MSYM)
!
      COMMON/S1/PI,PR,PR1,PR2,PR3,CON,COND
      COMMON/S2/SXXS,SXXN,SYYS,SYYN,SXYS,SXYN,UXS,UXN,UYS,UYN
!
      COS2B=COSB*COSB-SINB*SINB
      SIN2B=2.*SINB*COSB
!
      XB=(X-CX)*COSB+(Y-CY)*SINB
      YB=-(X-CX)*SINB+(Y-CY)*COSB
!
      R1S=(XB-A)*(XB-A)+YB*YB
      R2S=(XB+A)*(XB+A)+YB*YB
      FL1=0.5*ALOG(R1S)
      FL2=0.5*ALOG(R2S)
      FB2=CON*(FL1-FL2)
      IF (YB.NE.0.) GO TO 10
      FB3=0.
      IF (ABS(XB).LT.A) FB3=CON*PI
      GO TO 20
10    FB3=-CON*(ATAN((XB+A)/YB)-ATAN((XB-A)/YB))
20    FB1=YB*FB3+CON*((XB-A)*FL1-(XB+A)*FL2)
      FB4=CON*(YB/R1S-YB/R2S)
      FB5=CON*((XB-A)/R1S-(XB+A)/R2S)
!
      UXPS=COND*(PR3*COSB*FB1+YB*(SINB*FB2+COSB*FB3))
      UXPN=COND*(-PR3*SINB*FB1-YB*(COSB*FB2-SINB*FB3))
      UYPS=COND*(PR3*SINB*FB1-YB*(COSB*FB2-SINB*FB3))
      UYPN=COND*(PR3*COSB*FB1-YB*(SINB*FB2+COSB*FB3))
!
      SXXPS=FB2+PR2*(COS2B*FB2-SIN2B*FB3)+YB*(COS2B*FB4+SIN2B*FB5)
      SXXPN=FB3-PR1*(SIN2B*FB2+COS2B*FB3)+YB*(SIN2B*FB4-COS2B*FB5)
      SYYPS=FB2-PR2*(COS2B*FB2-SIN2B*FB3)-YB*(COS2B*FB4+SIN2B*FB5)
      SYYPN=FB3+PR1*(SIN2B*FB2+COS2B*FB3)-YB*(SIN2B*FB4-COS2B*FB5)
      SXYPS=PR2*(SIN2B*FB2+COS2B*FB3)+YB*(SIN2B*FB4-COS2B*FB5)
      SXYPN=PR1*(COS2B*FB2-SIN2B*FB3)-YB*(COS2B*FB4+SIN2B*FB5)
!
      UXS=UXS+MSYM*UXPS
      UXN=UXN+UXPN
      UYS=UYS+MSYM*UYPS
      UYN=UYN+UYPN
!
      SXXS=SXXS+MSYM*SXXPS
      SXXN=SXXN+SXXPN
      SYYS=SYYS+MSYM*SYYPS
      SYYN=SYYN+SYYPN
      SXYS=SXYS+MSYM*SXYPS
      SXYN=SXYN+SXYPN
!
      RETURN
      END
!
      SUBROUTINE SOLVE(N)
!
      COMMON/S3/A(100,100),B(100),X(100)
!
      NB=N-1
      DO 20 J=1,NB
      L=J+1
      DO 20 JJ=L,N
      XM=A(JJ,J)/A(J,J)
      DO 10 I=J,N
10    A(JJ,I)=A(JJ,I)-A(J,I)*XM
20    B(JJ)=B(JJ)-B(J)*XM
!
      X(N)=B(N)/A(N,N)
      DO 40 J=1,NB
      JJ=N-J
      L=JJ+1
      SUMM=0.
      DO 30 I=L,N
30    SUMM=SUMM+A(JJ,I)*X(I)
40    X(JJ)=(B(JJ)-SUMM)/A(JJ,JJ)
!
      RETURN
      END


Line 94 is: X[N-1] = B[N-1] / A[N-1][N-1];
Input data:
6,2,4
0.2, 7.0000E+04,0,0
1.0000E+02,0,0

1,1.0,0.0,0.9659,0.2588,1,0.0,0.0
1,0.9659,0.2588,0.8660,0.5000,1,0.0,0.0
1,0.8660,0.5000,0.7071,0.7071,1,0.0,0.0
1,0.7071,0.7071,0.5000,0.8660,1,0.0,0.0
1,0.5000,0.8660,0.2588,0.9659,1,0.0,0.0
1,0.2588,0.9659,0.0,1.0,1,0.0,0.0

1.0,0.0,4.0,0.0,5

0.0,1.0,0.0,4.0,5

I am waiting:
NUMBE_R OF STRAIGHT-LINE SEGMENTS (EACH COUNTING AT LEAST ONE BOUNDARY ELEMENT) USED T_O DEFINE BOUNDARIES =  6

NUMBE_R OF STRAIGHT-LINE SEGMENTS USED T_O SPECIFY OTHER LOCATIONS (IE, NO_T ON A BOUNDARY) WHER_E RESULTS ARE T_O BE FOUND =  2

THE LINES X = XS =      0.0000 AND Y = YS =      0.0000 ARE LINES OF SYMMETRY

POISSONS RATIO =  0.20

YOUNGS MODULUS = 0.7000E+05

XX-COMPONENT OF FIELD STRESS = 0.1000E+03

YY-COMPONENT OF FIELD STRESS = 0.0000E+00

XY-COMPONENT OF FIELD STRESS = 0.0000E+00

BOUNDARY ELEMENT DAT_A

ELEMENT     KODE  X (CENTER)  Y (CENTER)      LENGTH       ANGLE  US OR SIGMA-SUN OR SIGMA-N
        1        1      0.9829      0.1294      0.2610       97.51     0.0000E+00     0.0000E+00
        2        1      0.9160      0.3794      0.2611      112.50     0.0000E+00     0.0000E+00
        3        1      0.7865      0.6035      0.2610      127.50     0.0000E+00     0.0000E+00
        4        1      0.6035      0.7865      0.2610      142.50     0.0000E+00     0.0000E+00
        5        1      0.3794      0.9160      0.2611      157.50     0.0000E+00     0.0000E+00
        6        1      0.1294      0.9829      0.2610      172.49     0.0000E+00     0.0000E+00

DISPLACEMENTS AND STRESSES AT MIDPOINTS OF BOUNDARY ELEMENTS

ELEMENT        UX        UY        US UN        SIGXX     SIGYY     SIGXY     SIGMA-S     SIGMA-N   SIGMA-T
         1  0.002847 -0.000149 -0.000519 -0.002803      -1.6     -91.5      12.1       0.0      -0.0     -93.1
         2  0.002662 -0.000433 -0.001418 -0.002294      -6.1     -35.3      14.6       0.0      -0.0     -41.4
         3  0.002299 -0.000678 -0.001937 -0.001411      17.9      30.4     -23.3       0.0       0.0      48.3
         4  0.001776 -0.000868 -0.001937 -0.000392      95.5      56.2     -73.3      -0.0       0.0     151.7
         5  0.001123 -0.000995 -0.001418  0.000490     206.0      35.3     -85.3      -0.0      -0.0     241.3
         6  0.000384 -0.001059 -0.000519  0.000999     288.1       5.0     -38.0       0.0       0.0     293.1

DISPLACEMENTS AND STRESSES AT SPECIFIED POINTS I_N THE BODY

POINT    X CO-ORD    Y CO-ORD          UX          UY       SIGXX       SIGYY       SIGXY
        1      1.5000      0.0000    0.002246   -0.000000        14.8        -8.0        -0.0
        2      2.0000      0.0000    0.001772   -0.000000        44.4         3.2        -0.0
        3      2.5000      0.0000    0.001451   -0.000000        62.1         4.3         0.0
        4      3.0000      0.0000    0.001223   -0.000000        72.9         3.9        -0.0
        5      3.5000      0.0000    0.001056   -0.000000        79.7         3.2        -0.0
        6      4.0000      0.0000    0.000929   -0.000000        84.3         2.7        -0.0
        7      0.0000      1.5000    0.000000   -0.001050       154.5        38.6        -0.0
        8      0.0000      2.0000   -0.000000   -0.000876       123.0        29.4        -0.0
        9      0.0000      2.5000   -0.000000   -0.000733       112.4        21.1        -0.0
       10      0.0000      3.0000   -0.000000   -0.000626       107.8        15.5         0.0
       11      0.0000      3.5000   -0.000000   -0.000544       105.3        11.8        -0.0
       12      0.0000      4.0000   -0.000000   -0.000480       103.9         9.2        -0.0```


c++ uses 0 based indices. Your code is simpler to read and understand if you start to count at 0, even when it does not matter. For example for (int N = 1; N <= NUMBS; ++N) the N is not used anywhere so its easy to make it for (int N = 0; N < NUMBS; ++N) to have one loop less to worry about. <= has the smell of out of bounds

by the way, for more than 33 years now Fortran has supported identifiers that are much longer than 6 letters (I think Fortran90 did 31 characters, and it's pretty unusal to use CAPS LOCK for subprogram names in modern Fortran, too. Also, whitespace: use it. Lines like SIG_N=PXX*SINB*SINB-2.*PXY*SINB*COSB+PYY*COSB*COSB are just close to impossible to read correctly on the first try. This looks like someone forced you to time travel back to the late 1960s, and that didn't happen – you've tagged this tag:fortran90.

Recommendation: Convert the ALL_CAPS identifiers to something else. By long-standing C convention, ALL_CAPS is reserved for use with #define macros as a warning to readers that preprocessor wizardry is taking place behind the scenes. Confuse people or lead them into bad assumptions and they (even future-you) will reward your efforts by writing bugs.

Both programs could do with a lot more functions to make them easier to debug. You could however step both programs line by line in a debugger even now to see where they start diverging

Yep, No matter how you do this: I'd say you start by writing a simple C++ wrapper around your legacy  Fortran functionality, and a set of good unit tests that show that behaviour hasn't changed. No unit test that proves your program does the same as before, no claiming you ported to a different language.

After that mandatory part, you'd then start separating out your old fortran into fortran subroutines, testing that the overall program still does the same. Use your IDE to generously rename variables – calling something SXXPN is not nearly as helpful as calling it, for example hessian_entry_doubly_x. Then, you translate these fortran subroutines to C++. The amount of GOTO in your Fortran original will not work out well in a C++ translation. You can't do a verbatim translation of Fortran to C++ here – scoping will not allow you.

Side note: Translation is HARD. In order to translate code you need to know both languages well. The best path forward is to read the source code and fully understand all of the behaviours it describes. Then you reimplement that behaviour in the destination language, taking advantage of the new language's idioms and observing its best practices. Then you exhaustively test the original against the new version to ensure both produce the same results. Often it's faster to go back to the original design or algorithm notes and work from those rather than the original code.

Another thing of interest: What input do you give and what output do you expect?

to stress the "translation needs proficiency in the target language part": your initl function is pretty much useless, and would much be omitted completely, by making the variables it sets all local variables that get initialized to value-initalized to 0  – that will probably make it easier for the compiler to write good code. And I mean, the original code also leaves a lot questions open. NUMBE is a strange variable; instead of just setting it NUMBE+=NUM every row, the programmer chose to increment it by 1, NUM times. That's simply inefficient, and also really hides the intent! Bad.

The input you added results in Fortran runtime error: Bad value during integer read

One thing that is a show stopper is that your C++ program has undefined behavior. "AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow" -  I suggest that you examine what n - 1 is in x[n - 1] = b[n - 1] / a[n - 1][n - 1]; - After changing that line to x.at(n - 1) = b.at(n - 1) / a.at(n - 1).at(n - 1); I got an exception: terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'   what():  vector::_M_range_check: __n (which is 11) >= this->size() (which is 6)

... and the above exception happens because x.size() is 6 and you try to access element 11.

Later in the solve function jj becomes 12 which is again out of bounds in x[jj] = (b[jj] - summ) / a[jj][jj];.

@Mark, your code wil RUN (but not produce correct answers) if you do the following. Replace solve(n, c, b, a); by solve(n, c, b, p);, having declared p as the correct size beforehand:  vector<double> p(2*numbe);. In procedure solve, replace jj = n-j by jj=n-2-j (it should refer to the penultimate index). This runs, but produces the wrong answer. One reason for that is that your boundary conditions are wrong, as you don't understand what the computed gotos are doing in Fortran. You have also hard-wired the size of c[][].

OK, here's a C++ version which will get the ball rolling. It gives the same numerical output as the Fortran version. There's a certain amount of repetition, so it could be improved.
I've dealt with the 0-based (C++) versus 1-based (Fortran) arrays simply by taking the coward's way out and making the arrays one element larger than they need to be. Element[0] in each array isn't used. Fixing this runs the risk of having input files that don't work with both Fortran and C++ versions. I've also used fixed-size arrays (despite using vectors); this needs improving, but the format of the input file doesn't make that easy. Add a check that you don't exceed array bounds if necessary.
The Fortran code is very old (Fortran 66, I think). Hollerith constants and computed gotos no longer exist in the language. It might have been better to convert it to modern Fortran first - the world moves on. I had great difficulty even compiling the Fortran sample. I've either eradicated the computed-goto sections or changed them for switch statements in C++.
I have modified the input file only by removing the title line and changing the commas to spaces; trying to read fixed field widths is a nightmare in any language. Please use the input file below the code.
C++ Code
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

//---------- Some useful derived types -----------

struct Stress
{
   double xx;
   double yy;
   double xy;
   Stress( double a = 0.0, double b = 0.0, double c = 0.0 ) : xx(a), yy(b), xy(c) {};
};
Stress operator + ( const Stress &a, const Stress &b  ){ return Stress( a.xx + b.xx, a.yy + b.yy, a.xy + b.xy ); }
Stress operator * ( double a, const Stress &b ){ return Stress( a * b.xx, a * b.yy, a * b.xy ); }
Stress operator * ( const Stress &a, double b ){ return b * a; }
istream &operator >> ( istream &in, Stress &a ){ return in >> a.xx >> a.yy >> a.xy; }
ostream &operator << ( ostream &out, const Stress &a ){ return out << a.xx << ",  " << a.yy << ",  " << a.xy; }


struct Point{
   double x;
   double y;
   Point( double a = 0.0, double b = 0.0 ) : x(a), y(b) {};
};
Point operator + ( const Point &a, const Point &b  ){ return Point( a.x + b.x, a.y + b.y ); }
Point operator * ( double a, const Point &b ){ return Point( a * b.x, a * b.y ); }
Point operator * ( const Point &a, double b ){ return b * a; }


struct TestCase
{
   double pr, pr1, pr2, pr3;
   double con, cond;
};

//---------- Some constants ----------------------

const double PI = 4.0 * atan( 1.0 );
const int NMAX = 50;

//---------- Function declarations ---------------

void coeff( double x, double y, double cx, double cy, double a, double cosb,double sinb, int msym,
            const TestCase &T, Stress &Ss, Stress &Sn, Point &Us, Point &Un );
vector<double> solve( int n, vector<vector<double>> A, vector<double> b );

//------------------------------------------------

int main()
{
   string title;
   int numbs, numos, numpb;
   int ksym, kode;
   int num;
   double PR, E;
   double xsym, ysym;
   double xbeg, ybeg, xend, yend;
   double bvs, bvn;
   Stress Pf;

   vector<vector<double>> c( 1 + 2 * NMAX, vector<double>( 1 + 2 * NMAX ) );
   vector<double> b( 1 + 2 * NMAX );
   vector<double> xm( 1 + NMAX ), ym( 1 + NMAX ), a( 1 + NMAX ), cosbet( 1 + NMAX ), sinbet( 1 + NMAX );
   vector<int> kod( 1 + NMAX );

   // Input
   ifstream in( "input.txt" );
// getline( in, title );                // Stopped reading the title; it isn't in the input file
   in >> numbs >> numos >> ksym;
   in >> PR >> E >> xsym >> ysym;
   in >> Pf;

   cout << title << '\n';
   cout << "Number of straight-line segments (each counting at least one boundary element) used to define boundaries = " << numbs << '\n';
   cout << "Number of straight-line segments used to specify other locations (ie, not on a boundary) where results are to be found = " << numos << '\n';
   if ( ksym == 2 || ksym == 4 ) cout << "The line x = " << xsym << " is a line of symmetry\n";
   if ( ksym == 3 || ksym == 4 ) cout << "The line y = " << ysym << " is a line of symmetry\n";
   cout << "Poisson's ratio = " << PR << "   Young's modulus = " << E << '\n';
   cout << "Field stress: xx, yy, xy = " << Pf << '\n';

   TestCase T;
   T.con = 1 / ( 4 * PI * ( 1 - PR ) );
   T.cond = ( 1 + PR ) / E;
   T.pr1 = 1 - 2 * PR;
   T.pr2 = 2 * ( 1 - PR );
   T.pr3 = 3 - 4 * PR;

   // Define locations, sizes, orientations and boundary conditions of boundary elements
   int numbe = 0;
   for ( int n = 1; n <= numbs; n++ )
   {
      in >> num >> xbeg >> ybeg >> xend >> yend >> kode >> bvs >> bvn;
      double xd = ( xend - xbeg ) / num;
      double yd = ( yend - ybeg ) / num;
      double sw = sqrt( xd * xd + yd * yd );
      for ( int ne = 1; ne <= num; ne++ )
      {
         numbe++;
         int m = numbe;
         xm[m] = xbeg + 0.5 * ( 2 * ne - 1 ) * xd;
         ym[m] = ybeg + 0.5 * ( 2 * ne - 1 ) * yd;
         a[m] = 0.5 * sw;
         sinbet[m] = yd / sw;
         cosbet[m] = xd / sw;
         kod[m] = kode;
         int mn = 2 * m;
         int ms = mn - 1;
         b[ms] = bvs;
         b[mn] = bvn;
      }
   }

   #define FMT << " " << setw( 15 ) << setprecision( 4 ) << scientific <<
   cout << "Boundary element data\n";
   cout FMT "element" FMT "kode" FMT "x(center)" FMT "y(center)" FMT "length" FMT "angle" FMT "us or sigma-s" FMT "un or sigma-n" << '\n';
   for ( int m = 1; m <= numbe; m++ )
   {
      double size = 2 * a[m];
      double angle = 180 * atan2( sinbet[m], cosbet[m] ) / PI;
      cout FMT m FMT kod[m] FMT xm[m] FMT ym[m] FMT size FMT angle FMT b[2*m-1] FMT b[2*m] << '\n';
   }


   // Adjust stress boundary values to account for initial stresses.
   for ( int n = 1; n <= numbe; n++ )
   {
      int nn = 2 * n;
      int ns = nn - 1;
      double cosb = cosbet[n];
      double sinb = sinbet[n];
      double sigmas = ( Pf.yy - Pf.xx ) * sinb * cosb + Pf.xy * ( cosb * cosb - sinb * sinb );
      double sigman = Pf.xx * sinb * sinb - 2 * Pf.xy * sinb * cosb + Pf.yy * cosb * cosb;
      if ( kod[n] == 1 || kod[n] == 4 ) b[ns] -= sigmas;
      if ( kod[n] == 1 || kod[n] == 3 ) b[nn] -= sigman;
   }

   // Compute influence coefficients and set up system of algebraic equations.
   for ( int i = 1; i <= numbe; i++ )
   {
      int in = 2 * i;
      int is = in - 1;
      double xi = xm[i], yi = ym[i], cosbi = cosbet[i], sinbi = sinbet[i];
      int kode = kod[i];
      for ( int j = 1; j <= numbe; j++ )
      {
         int jn = 2 * j;
         int js = jn - 1;
         double xj = xm[j], yj = ym[j], cosbj = cosbet[j], sinbj = sinbet[j], aj = a[j];
         Stress Ss, Sn;
         Point Us, Un;
         coeff( xi, yi, xj, yj, aj, cosbj, sinbj, +1, T, Ss, Sn, Us, Un );
         switch( ksym )
         {
            case 1:
               break;
            case 2:
               xj = 2 * xsym - xm[j];
               coeff( xi, yi, xj, yj, aj,  cosbj, -sinbj, -1, T, Ss, Sn, Us, Un );
               break;
            case 3:
               yj = 2 * ysym - ym[j];
               coeff( xi, yi, xj, yj, aj, -cosbj,  sinbj, -1, T, Ss, Sn, Us, Un );
               break;
            case 4:
               xj = 2 * xsym - xm[j];
               coeff( xi, yi, xj, yj, aj,  cosbj, -sinbj, -1, T, Ss, Sn, Us, Un );
               xj = xm[j];
               yj = 2 * ysym - ym[j];
               coeff( xi, yi, xj, yj, aj, -cosbj,  sinbj, -1, T, Ss, Sn, Us, Un );
               xj = 2 * xsym - xm[j];
               coeff( xi, yi, xj, yj, aj, -cosbj, -sinbj, +1, T, Ss, Sn, Us, Un );
               break;
         }
         switch( kode )
         {
            case 1:
               c[is][js] = ( Ss.yy - Ss.xx ) * sinbi * cosbi + Ss.xy * ( cosbi * cosbi - sinbi * sinbi );
               c[is][jn] = ( Sn.yy - Sn.xx ) * sinbi * cosbi + Sn.xy * ( cosbi * cosbi - sinbi * sinbi );
               c[in][js] =   Ss.xx           * sinbi * sinbi - 2 * Ss.xy * sinbi * cosbi + Ss.yy * cosbi * cosbi;
               c[in][jn] =   Sn.xx           * sinbi * sinbi - 2 * Sn.xy * sinbi * cosbi + Sn.yy * cosbi * cosbi;
               break;
            case 2:
               c[is][js] =  Us.x * cosbi + Us.y * sinbi;
               c[is][jn] =  Un.x * cosbi + Un.y * sinbi;
               c[in][js] = -Us.x * sinbi + Us.y * cosbi;
               c[in][jn] = -Un.x * sinbi + Un.y * cosbi;
               break;
            case 3:
               c[is][js] = Us.x  * cosbi + Us.y * sinbi;
               c[is][jn] = Un.x  * cosbi + Un.y * sinbi;
               c[in][js] = Ss.xx * sinbi * sinbi - 2 * Ss.xy * sinbi * cosbi + Ss.yy * cosbi * cosbi;
               c[in][jn] = Sn.xx * sinbi * sinbi - 2 * Sn.xy * sinbi * cosbi + Sn.yy * cosbi * cosbi;
               break;
            case 4:
               c[is][js] = ( Ss.yy - Ss.xx ) * sinbi * cosbi + Ss.xy * ( cosbi * cosbi - sinbi * sinbi );
               c[is][jn] = ( Sn.yy - Sn.xx ) * sinbi * cosbi + Sn.xy * ( cosbi * cosbi - sinbi * sinbi );
               c[in][js] = -Us.x * sinbi + Us.y * cosbi;
               c[in][jn] = -Un.x * sinbi + Un.y * cosbi;
               break;
         }
      }
   }

   // Solve system of algebraic equations.
   vector<double> p = solve( 2 * numbe, c, b );

   // Compute boundary displacements and stresses.
   cout << "Displacements and stresses at midpoints of boundary elements\n";
   cout FMT "element" FMT "ux" FMT "uy" FMT "us" FMT "un" FMT "sigxx" FMT "sigyy" FMT "sigxy" FMT "sigma-s" FMT "sigma-n" FMT "sigma-t" << '\n';

   for ( int i = 1; i <= numbe; i++ )
   {
      double xi = xm[i], yi = ym[i], cosbi = cosbet[i], sinbi = sinbet[i];
      Stress Sig = Pf;
      Point U;
      for ( int j = 1; j <= numbe; j++ )
      {
         int jn = 2 * j;
         int js = jn - 1;
         double xj = xm[j], yj = ym[j], aj = a[j], cosbj = cosbet[j], sinbj = sinbet[j];
         Point Us, Un;
         Stress Ss, Sn;
         coeff( xi, yi, xj, yj, aj, cosbj, sinbj, + 1, T, Ss, Sn, Us, Un );
         switch( ksym )
         {
            case 1:
               break;
            case 2:
               xj = 2 * xsym - xm[j];
               coeff( xi, yi, xj, yj, aj,  cosbj, -sinbj, -1, T, Ss, Sn, Us, Un );
               break;
            case 3:
               yj = 2 * ysym - ym[j];
               coeff( xi, yi, xj, yj, aj, -cosbj,  sinbj, -1, T, Ss, Sn, Us, Un );
               break;
            case 4:
               xj = 2 * xsym - xm[j];
               coeff( xi, yi, xj, yj, aj,  cosbj, -sinbj, -1, T, Ss, Sn, Us, Un );
               xj = xm[j];
               yj = 2 * ysym - ym[j];
               coeff( xi, yi, xj, yj, aj, -cosbj,  sinbj, -1, T, Ss, Sn, Us, Un );
               xj = 2 * xsym - xm[j];
               coeff( xi, yi, xj, yj, aj, -cosbj, -sinbj, +1, T, Ss, Sn, Us, Un );
               break;
         }
         U   = U   + p[js] * Us + p[jn] * Un;
         Sig = Sig + p[js] * Ss + p[jn] * Sn;
      }
      double us =  U.x * cosbi + U.y * sinbi;
      double un = -U.x * sinbi + U.y * cosbi;
      double sigmas  = ( Sig.yy - Sig.xx ) * sinbi * cosbi + Sig.xy * ( cosbi * cosbi-sinbi * sinbi );
      double sigman  =   Sig.xx            * sinbi * sinbi - 2 * Sig.xy * sinbi * cosbi + Sig.yy * cosbi * cosbi;
      double sigmat  =   Sig.xx            * cosbi * cosbi + 2 * Sig.xy * cosbi * sinbi + Sig.yy * sinbi * sinbi;
      cout FMT i FMT U.x FMT U.y FMT us FMT un FMT Sig.xx FMT Sig.yy FMT Sig.xy FMT sigmas FMT sigman FMT sigmat << '\n';
   }

   // Compute displacements and stresses at specified points in body
   if ( numos > 0 )
   {
      cout << "Displacements and stresses at specified points in the body\n";
      cout FMT "point" FMT "x co-ord" FMT "y co-ord" FMT "u" FMT "uy" FMT "sigxx" FMT "sigyy" FMT "sigxy" << '\n';
   
      int npoint = 0;
      for ( int n = 1; n <= numos; n++ )
      {
         in >> xbeg >> ybeg >> xend >> yend >> numpb;
      
         int nump = numpb + 1;
         double delx = ( xend - xbeg ) / nump;
         double dely = ( yend - ybeg ) / nump;
         if ( numpb > 0 ) nump++;
         if ( delx * delx + dely * dely == 0.0 ) nump = 1;
      
         for ( int ni = 1; ni <= nump; ni++ )
         {
            double xp = xbeg + ( ni - 1 ) * delx;
            double yp = ybeg + ( ni - 1 ) * dely;
         
            Point U;
            Stress Sig = Pf;
            bool ok = true;
            for ( int j = 1; j <= numbe; j++ )
            {
               int jn = 2 * j;
               int js = jn - 1;
               double xj = xm[j], yj = ym[j], aj = a[j];
               double cosbj = cosbet[j], sinbj = sinbet[j];
               if ( sqrt( ( xp - xj ) * ( xp - xj ) + ( yp - yj ) * ( yp - yj ) ) < 2 * aj ) 
               {
                  ok = false;
                  break;
               }

               Point Us, Un;
               Stress Ss, Sn;
               coeff( xp, yp, xj, yj, aj, cosbj, sinbj, +1, T, Ss, Sn, Us, Un );
               switch( ksym )
               {
                  case 1:
                     break;
                  case 2:
                     xj = 2 * xsym - xm[j];
                     coeff( xp, yp, xj, yj, aj,  cosbj, -sinbj, -1, T, Ss, Sn, Us, Un );
                     break;
                  case 3:
                     yj = 2 * ysym - ym[j];
                     coeff( xp, yp, xj, yj, aj, -cosbj,  sinbj, -1, T, Ss, Sn, Us, Un );
                     break;
                  case 4:
                     xj = 2 * xsym - xm[j];
                     coeff( xp, yp, xj, yj, aj,  cosbj, -sinbj, -1, T, Ss, Sn, Us, Un );
                     xj = xm[j];
                     yj = 2 * ysym - ym[j];
                     coeff( xp, yp, xj, yj, aj, -cosbj,  sinbj, -1, T, Ss, Sn, Us, Un );
                     xj = 2 * xsym - xm[j];
                     coeff( xp, yp, xj, yj, aj, -cosbj, -sinbj, +1, T, Ss, Sn, Us, Un );
                     break;
               }
               U   = U   + p[js] * Us + p[jn] * Un;
               Sig = Sig + p[js] * Ss + p[jn] * Sn;
            }
      
            if ( ok )
            {
               npoint++;
               cout FMT npoint FMT xp FMT yp FMT U.x FMT U.y FMT Sig.xx FMT Sig.yy FMT Sig.xy << '\n';
            }
         }
      }
   }
}

//------------------------------------------------

void coeff( double x, double y, double cx, double cy, double a, double cosb,double sinb, int msym,
            const TestCase &T, Stress &Ss, Stress &Sn, Point &Us, Point &Un )
{
   double cos2b = cosb * cosb - sinb * sinb;
   double sin2b = 2 * sinb * cosb;

   double xb =  ( x - cx ) * cosb + ( y - cy ) * sinb;
   double yb = -( x - cx ) * sinb + ( y - cy ) * cosb;
   double r1s = ( xb - a ) * ( xb - a ) + yb * yb;
   double r2s = ( xb + a ) * ( xb + a ) + yb * yb;
   double fl1 = 0.5 * log( r1s );
   double fl2 = 0.5 * log( r2s );
   double fb2 = T.con * ( fl1 - fl2 );
   double fb3 = 0.0;
   if ( yb == 0.0 )
   {
      if ( abs( xb ) < a ) fb3 = T.con * PI;
   }
   else
   {
      fb3 = -T.con * ( atan( ( xb + a ) / yb ) - atan( ( xb - a ) / yb ) );
   }
   double fb1 = yb * fb3 + T.con * ( ( xb - a ) * fl1 - ( xb + a ) * fl2 );
   double fb4 = T.con * ( yb / r1s - yb / r2s );
   double fb5 = T.con * ( ( xb - a ) / r1s - ( xb + a ) / r2s );

   Point Ups, Upn;
   Ups.x = T.cond * (  T.pr3 * cosb * fb1 + yb * ( sinb * fb2 + cosb * fb3 ) );
   Upn.x = T.cond * ( -T.pr3 * sinb * fb1 - yb * ( cosb * fb2 - sinb * fb3 ) );
   Ups.y = T.cond * (  T.pr3 * sinb * fb1 - yb * ( cosb * fb2 - sinb * fb3 ) );
   Upn.y = T.cond * (  T.pr3 * cosb * fb1 - yb * ( sinb * fb2 + cosb * fb3 ) );

   Stress Sps, Spn;
   Sps.xx = fb2 + T.pr2 * ( cos2b * fb2 - sin2b * fb3 ) + yb * ( cos2b * fb4 + sin2b * fb5 );
   Spn.xx = fb3 - T.pr1 * ( sin2b * fb2 + cos2b * fb3 ) + yb * ( sin2b * fb4 - cos2b * fb5 );
   Sps.yy = fb2 - T.pr2 * ( cos2b * fb2 - sin2b * fb3 ) - yb * ( cos2b * fb4 + sin2b * fb5 );
   Spn.yy = fb3 + T.pr1 * ( sin2b * fb2 + cos2b * fb3 ) - yb * ( sin2b * fb4 - cos2b * fb5 );
   Sps.xy =       T.pr2 * ( sin2b * fb2 + cos2b * fb3 ) + yb * ( sin2b * fb4 - cos2b * fb5 );
   Spn.xy =       T.pr1 * ( cos2b * fb2 - sin2b * fb3 ) - yb * ( cos2b * fb4 + sin2b * fb5 );

   Us = Us + msym * Ups;
   Un = Un +        Upn;
   Ss = Ss + msym * Sps;
   Sn = Sn +        Spn;
}

//------------------------------------------------

vector<double> solve( int n, vector<vector<double>> A, vector<double> b )
{
   for ( int j = 1; j <= n - 1; j++ )
   {
      for ( int jj = j + 1; jj <= n; jj++ )
      {
         double xm = A[jj][j] / A[j][j];
         for ( int i = j; i <= n; i++ ) A[jj][i] -= A[j][i] * xm;
         b[jj] -= b[j] * xm;
      }
   }

   vector<double> x( b.size() );
   x[n] = b[n] / A[n][n];
   for ( int j = 1; j <= n - 1; j++ )
   {
      int jj = n - j;
      double summ = 0.0;
      for ( int i = jj + 1; i <= n; i++ ) summ += A[jj][i] * x[i];
      x[jj] = ( b[jj] - summ ) / A[jj][jj];
   }

   return x;
}

Input file (input.txt)
6 2 4
0.2  7.0000E+04 0 0
1.0000E+02 0 0

1 1.0 0.0 0.9659 0.2588 1 0.0 0.0
1 0.9659 0.2588 0.8660 0.5000 1 0.0 0.0
1 0.8660 0.5000 0.7071 0.7071 1 0.0 0.0
1 0.7071 0.7071 0.5000 0.8660 1 0.0 0.0
1 0.5000 0.8660 0.2588 0.9659 1 0.0 0.0
1 0.2588 0.9659 0.0 1.0 1 0.0 0.0

1.0 0.0 4.0 0.0 5

0.0 1.0 0.0 4.0 5

Output (screen capture)
Number of straight-line segments (each counting at least one boundary element) used to define boundaries = 6
Number of straight-line segments used to specify other locations (ie, not on a boundary) where results are to be found = 2
The line x = 0 is a line of symmetry
The line y = 0 is a line of symmetry
Poisson's ratio = 0.2   Young's modulus = 70000
Field stress: xx, yy, xy = 100,  0,  0
Boundary element data
         element            kode       x(center)       y(center)          length           angle   us or sigma-s   un or sigma-n
               1               1      9.8295e-01      1.2940e-01      2.6104e-01      9.7506e+01      0.0000e+00      0.0000e+00
               2               1      9.1595e-01      3.7940e-01      2.6107e-01      1.1250e+02      0.0000e+00      0.0000e+00
               3               1      7.8655e-01      6.0355e-01      2.6104e-01      1.2750e+02      0.0000e+00      0.0000e+00
               4               1      6.0355e-01      7.8655e-01      2.6104e-01      1.4250e+02      0.0000e+00      0.0000e+00
               5               1      3.7940e-01      9.1595e-01      2.6107e-01      1.5750e+02      0.0000e+00      0.0000e+00
               6               1      1.2940e-01      9.8295e-01      2.6104e-01      1.7249e+02      0.0000e+00      0.0000e+00
Displacements and stresses at midpoints of boundary elements
         element              ux              uy              us              un           sigxx           sigyy           sigxy         sigma-s         sigma-n         sigma-t
               1      2.8470e-03     -1.4881e-04     -5.1944e-04     -2.8031e-03     -1.5886e+00     -9.1501e+01      1.2056e+01      5.3291e-15      2.0428e-14     -9.3089e+01
               2      2.6619e-03     -4.3250e-04     -1.4182e-03     -2.2938e-03     -6.0549e+00     -3.5296e+01      1.4619e+01     -1.7764e-15     -2.6645e-15     -4.1351e+01
               3      2.2991e-03     -6.7780e-04     -1.9373e-03     -1.4114e-03      1.7882e+01      3.0376e+01     -2.3307e+01      8.8818e-15      1.0658e-14      4.8258e+01
               4      1.7759e-03     -8.6797e-04     -1.9373e-03     -3.9241e-04      9.5517e+01      5.6230e+01     -7.3287e+01      7.1054e-15      2.1316e-14      1.5175e+02
               5      1.1228e-03     -9.9532e-04     -1.4182e-03      4.8992e-04      2.0600e+02      3.5338e+01     -8.5321e+01     -1.4211e-14      1.0658e-14      2.4134e+02
               6      3.8430e-04     -1.0586e-03     -5.1929e-04      9.9930e-04      2.8809e+02      5.0017e+00     -3.7960e+01      0.0000e+00     -1.7764e-15      2.9310e+02
Displacements and stresses at specified points in the body
           point        x co-ord        y co-ord               u              uy           sigxx           sigyy           sigxy
               1      1.5000e+00      0.0000e+00      2.2461e-03     -5.0975e-20      1.4850e+01     -7.9906e+00      1.2179e-15
               2      2.0000e+00      0.0000e+00      1.7725e-03      3.6011e-20      4.4416e+01      3.1933e+00      1.8014e-16
               3      2.5000e+00      0.0000e+00      1.4505e-03     -6.2163e-20      6.2148e+01      4.3214e+00     -2.1320e-16
               4      3.0000e+00      0.0000e+00      1.2235e-03     -1.0520e-19      7.2855e+01      3.8602e+00     -6.0026e-17
               5      3.5000e+00      0.0000e+00      1.0563e-03      1.5125e-19      7.9676e+01      3.2167e+00     -2.2186e-16
               6      4.0000e+00      0.0000e+00      9.2859e-04      1.3077e-19      8.4250e+01      2.6519e+00     -3.3073e-16
               7      0.0000e+00      1.5000e+00      0.0000e+00     -1.0503e-03      1.5449e+02      3.8647e+01      0.0000e+00
               8      0.0000e+00      2.0000e+00      0.0000e+00     -8.7560e-04      1.2296e+02      2.9426e+01      0.0000e+00
               9      0.0000e+00      2.5000e+00      0.0000e+00     -7.3302e-04      1.1242e+02      2.1110e+01      0.0000e+00
              10      0.0000e+00      3.0000e+00      0.0000e+00     -6.2558e-04      1.0777e+02      1.5519e+01      0.0000e+00
              11      0.0000e+00      3.5000e+00      0.0000e+00     -5.4382e-04      1.0532e+02      1.1782e+01      0.0000e+00
              12      0.0000e+00      4.0000e+00      0.0000e+00     -4.8017e-04      1.0389e+02      9.2101e+00      0.0000e+00


Is it really worth doing the whole job from scratch for the asker in these types of questions? I get that the oroginal asker's rewriting attempt might have been bad but SO is not a code writing or code converting service and it is dubious whether they learn how to do it better next time. There hasn't been a single reply to the comments received.
